# Get sum of a column between two dates in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, count, numeric

I have a table like :

```
EmpId , LeaveDays, StartDate,       EndDate
------------------------------------------------------
1    , 4        , 24-Jan-2016,     27-Jan-2016
2    , 4        , 26-Jan-2016,     29-Jan-2016
1    , 3        , 15-Jan-2016,     17-Jan-2016
```

i am working on payroll report, above table is leave table. Now admin want to generate payroll report between two dates like '1 Jan 2016' to 25 Jan 2016. it will fetch 3 count for **user with Id 1**. but when admin goes to detail report there are 2 more leaves in this peroid i.e. 24, 25 jan.

I have used following query:

```
select ISNULL(sum(convert(float,NumberOfDays)),0) from table
    WHERE FromDate >= '15-Jan-2016' and EndDate <='25-Jan-2016'
```

We don't want to do this by loop. i don't want to iterate the loop for number of dates coming between fromdate and Enddate. is there any way in which we can achieve this goal. Please help me.

**UPDATE:**
Sorry my question is bit confusing: let try to explain the things again:

We have two records for empId=1 okay?

i.e.

```
EmpId , LeaveDays, StartDate,       EndDate
------------------------------------------------------
1    , 4        , 24-Jan-2016,     27-Jan-2016
1    , 3        , 15-Jan-2016,     17-Jan-2016
```

Now when my startdate = 24-Jan-2016 and Enddate ='28-Jan-2016'.. What my above query will return is : "**7**". Right..

Now i am chainging the enddate to "25-Jan-2016". Now what my query will return is: **3** because as per my condition it will fetch only records having date less than by passing(enddate i.e. 25-jan-2016) date. so it will fetch only **3**.

but i want to get the result as **5**, means 3 for dates 15-17 jan and 2 for 24 and 25 th jan.

I hope my question is clear now.. :)

Comment: After reading your question, I'm not sure you made me confused or you are in confusion :O. But i have one question for you **how do you expect the changes done in select query will affects the data in the table?** FYI:- I'm not that downvoter

Comment: @SankarRaj, i am not updating the data, i just want to get the number of days between two dates..

Comment: -1 : I don't even know where to start : poor english, poor phrasing, poor description of the problem, poor formating. On top of that the question is also likely to be helpful to no more people than just you.

Comment: data is already in the table i need to fetch the data....

DateDiff will tell me the number of days between two dates. i want to get sum of the "LeaveDays" days column...

Comment: Okay now i understood your requirement you want no of leavedays between start and end date for a employee. Right?

Comment: @SankarRaj right, i want to generate payroll report, if admin select 1 jan 2016 to 31 Jan 2016, then if there is any leave started from jan and ends in feb, 

in this case how can i calculate the days come under the specific dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly you want:

1. A column in your table that details the number of days between two other columns.
2. This column should always reflect the latest data.

You can achieve this using a [Computed Column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188300.aspx).  These are virtual columns, the contents of which are calculated on demand.

**Example**

```
CREATE TABLE #Example
    (
        Id              INT,
        StartDate       DATE,
        EndDate         DATE,

        NumberOfDays    AS DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EndDate)
    )
;

/* Only start and end dates need adding, 
 * the number of days is calcualted.
 */
INSERT INTO #Example
    (
        Id,
        StartDate,
        EndDate
    )
VALUES
    (1, '2015-12-01', '2015-12-31'),
    (2, '2015-12-02', '2015-12-28')
;


-- Let's see what we have.
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Example
;
```

**Result**

```
Id  StartDate    EndDate     NumberOfDays
1   2015-12-01   2015-12-31  30
2   2015-12-02   2015-12-28  26
```

It looks like you are storing dates in a text column.  In my example I've  the [date data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187752.aspx).  Storing dates using the correct data type allows you to make use of SQLs many [date and time functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186724.aspx), which simplifies this task.

**EDIT**

I'd misunderstood.  The OP wanted to override the end date stored in the table.

This query counts the number of days between a start and end point, replacing any end point that exceeds a set date.

To do this I've used a [CASE expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx), which replaces end date outside the given range.  I've also added 1 to the result.  Without this we would be counting the difference between two days, instead of the inclusive number of days.

Again I've replace the text dates with date dates, so I can make use of SQL Server's rich date functionality.

**Override Example**

```
DECLARE @EndDate    DATE = '2016-01-25';

WITH Emp AS
    (
        /* CTE returns sample data for us to 
         * experiment with.
         */
        SELECT
            r.*
        FROM
            (
                VALUES
                    (1, 4, '2016-01-24', '2016-01-27'),
                    (1, 3, '2016-01-15', '2016-01-17')
            ) AS r(EmpId, LeaveDays, StartDate, EndDate)
    )
/* Returns the number of days between the start and end date.
 * If the end date exceeds a set limit this is used instead.
 */
SELECT
    EmpId,
    SUM(
        DATEDIFF(
            DAY,
            StartDate,
            CASE WHEN EndDate > @EndDate THEN @EndDate ELSE EndDate END
        ) + 1
    ) AS LeaveDays
FROM
    Emp
GROUP BY
    EmpId
;
```

Comment: data is already in the table i need to fetch the data.... DateDiff will tell me the number of days between two dates. i want to get sum of the "LeaveDays" days column

Comment: Are you saying the table has an end date of 27-Jan-2016, but they query needs to use 25-Jan-2016 instead?

Comment: i want to generate payroll report, if admin select 1 jan 2016 to 31 Jan 2016, then if there is any leave started from jan and ends in feb, in this case how can i calculate the days come under the specific dates

Answer (score 2):

This will get the leave days in the interval described in the parameters:

```
DECLARE @t table
(EmpId int, LeaveDays int, StartDate date,       EndDate date)
INSERT @t values
(1    , 4        , '24-Jan-2016',     '27-Jan-2016'),
(2    , 4        , '26-Jan-2016',     '29-Jan-2016'),
(1    , 3        , '15-Jan-2016',     '17-Jan-2016')

DECLARE @StartDate date = '14-Jan-2016' , @EndDate date= '25-Jan-2016'

-- adding 1 to include both days

SELECT 
  DATEDIFF(day, 
    CASE WHEN @StartDate < StartDate THEN StartDate ELSE @StartDate END,
    CASE WHEN @EndDate < EndDate THEN @EndDate ELSE EndDate END) +1
      LeaveDaysWithinInterval, 
  *
FROM @t
WHERE StartDate <= @EndDate
and @StartDate <= EndDate
```

Result:

```
LeaveDaysWithinInterval  EmpId  LeaveDays  StartDate   EndDate
2                        1      4          2016-01-24  2016-01-27
3                        1      3          2016-01-15  2016-01-17
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

```
declare @stdate datetime, @eddate datetime, @emp_cur cursor,@empid int
set @stdate = '2011-11-01 00:00:00.000'
set @eddate = '2011-11-30 00:00:00.000'


create table #temp(emp_id int,no_days int, st_date datetime,ed_date datetime)
insert into #temp
select employee_id, no_of_days,StartDate,EndDate from LeaveDays
where ( StartDate between @stdate and @eddate) or (EndDate between @stdate and @eddate) 

create table #temp1 (emp_id1 int, no_days1 int)
set @emp_cur= cursor scroll  for select emp_id from #temp
open @emp_cur
    fetch next from @emp_cur into @empid
    while(@@fetch_status = 0)
        begin
            insert into #temp1
            select emp_id, sum(no_days) - 
            ((select isnull(sum(datediff(day,st_date,@stdate)),0) from #temp where emp_id =@empid and st_date not between @stdate and @eddate) + 
            (select isnull(sum(datediff(day,@eddate,ed_date)),0) from #temp where emp_id =@empid and ed_date not between @stdate and @eddate)) from #temp where emp_id=@empid group by emp_id 
            fetch next from @emp_cur into @empid
        end
    close @emp_cur
deallocate @emp_cur
select distinct * from #temp1 order by emp_id1

drop Table #temp
drop Table #temp1
```

Hope This also helps...